# MYSQL searching for ID in array from DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, search

I have done searching, but everything I have found is reverse the way I need.

I have a database where one of the fields is a string of IDs, I want to search for a certain ID in that array I have in the DB already.

For instance, in the database it looks like this:

```
ID    Title    Spots Used
 1    test 1    1,3,5,8
 2    test 2    4,2,5,6,7
 3    test 3    3,5,2,1
```

I need to search for how many campaigns were used that have the spot that has the ID of 2 (should return both test 2 and test 3).

What would be the best way to go about this? So far, I can query the entire thing, run row by row, and do a `strpos` search for the number, but the problem is that when I end up getting more than 10 spots uploaded, 1 will return 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, etc.

If I need to provide more info, please let me know.

Comment: So like `SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE 2 IN (Spots Used)` or something?

Comment: normalise the db, that would help enormously

Comment: So, I am able to use a field in the `IN` clause?  I couldn't find that I could in any documentation I have read.

Comment: @Fred-ii- have you looked at the data? He's not trying to find fields matching an array of values, but finding a value in a field containing a comma separated list of values. `in` will not do the trick.

Comment: My mistake @GolezTrol Thanks for pointing that out. Comments deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these ids are stored as comma seperated then you can use [*FIND_IN_SET()*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2',`column_name`) >0
```

But storing comma separated values is bad idea if you are able to change your schema then first normalize your table structure

[**Database Normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Looks like this worked!  Been struggling for a little more than an hour. Thanks

Comment: @BrianLogan: This would work for now, but you seriously need to take a look at the last link. It'd save a lot of trouble down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You can have everything in just one table but c'mon what is it good for a relational database,

create two more tables , one will be Spot(id,spot_number) an the other one Campaigns_spot(id_campaign,id_spot), and the let the sql engine do it with a query , this way is far more efficient and you are going to be using a proper database relation.

the query then would be

```
select count(*) from campaign_spot where id_spot= X (whatever number you want).
```